# Why fetched data do not populate the state after i set them?

Tags: reactjs, api, state

Data fetched successfully but my state does not change.

I initialize the state categories as an empty [] then I want to set it to the data I fetched. Response is OK and I can see the data in the console.

It is an object with one pair: categories:Array(14) which is what I am looking for.

```
const [categories,setCategories] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMeals = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php"
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data.categories);      /*array (14)*/ 
      setCategories(data.categories.map((cat) => cat.strCategory));
      console.log(categories);          /*empty array*/
    };
    fetchMeals();
  },[]);
```

Why doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think the set works instantly; categories will be set on the next render. If you display categories in your component you should see the new value; your code looks right (although I'd add some error-checking for the fetch).

Comment: What is the structure of the objects inside data.category ? Moreover, `setCategory` is asynchronous so you don't see the `category` state updated at this stage.
Put you console.log(categories) outside the use effect.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async like operation so you would never see updated state synchronously (after invoking `setState`).
You can do alternatively:

```
const updatedCategiories = data.categories.map((cat) => cat.strCategory);
setCategories(updatedCategiories);
console.log(updatedCategiories);
```